# Android SetRequestRotation flips Activity landscape to portrait when auto rotate enabled

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to setRequestOrientation to a portrait but Activity rotates to landscape and set to portrait when auto-rotate enabled.
The Activity will support both landscape and portrait mode.
The problem will happen above Android 7.0.

Comment: Are you trying to do it in a specific activity?

Comment: It's Dynamic for every activity. Have settings to select orientation whether portrait or landscape. Setting to portrait but the phone in auto-rotate mode and keeping mobile in the landscape, the screen flips landscape to portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the screen orientation to follow the previous set orientation like this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.my.example.MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="behind" >
</activity>
```

Set it to **behind**.

Comment: No problem! Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

The default `android:screenOrientation` is `unspecified`. This means

> The default value. The system chooses the orientation. The policy it uses, and therefore the choices made in specific contexts, may differ from device to device.

In some tablets, for example, the default that the system will choose is landscape, so the system may be auto-rotating to landscape as soon as you start the activity, and then flipping from landscape to portrait when you do your setRequestOrientation.

So to prevent the system from behaving this way, you could try choosing the `android:screenOrientation` for each of those activities in your android manifest like:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.my.example.MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="locked" >
</activity>
```

or

```
<activity
    android:name="com.my.example.MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="behind" >
</activity>
```

depending on your app requirements. See the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element) for more information on these and other options.

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer.

Comment: No problem, sometimes it helps more to understand the reasons why things are happening. Good luck!